# CSS div rounded corners

Tags: css, html

I'm attempting to do the following...

Here's what I've got right now.. but it's not rendering correctly. Does anyone have any idea as to how I'd fix this?

**CSS**

```
    /* Curved Corners */
    .bl {
background: url(bl.gif) 0 100% no-repeat;
/*background-color:#EFFBEF;*/
width: 700px;
margin-left: auto ;
margin-right: auto ;}
    .br {
background: url(br.gif) 100% 100% no-repeat;
}
    .tl {
background: url(tl.gif) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
    .tr {
background: url(tr.gif) 100% 0 no-repeat;
}
    .clear {font-size: 1px; height: 1px}
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="bl"><div class="br"><div class="tl"><div class="tr">

        <div id="header">

    </div>

    <div id="footer">

    </div>

        </div></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Instead I suggest you use CSS3, which unlike other methods, does not require extraneous HTML or Javascript markup that notoriously causes any rounded element to 'flash' upon page load.

```
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px;
 -o-border-radius: 10px;
 -ms-border-radius: 10px;
 -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
```

This generator is also helpful: http://borderradius.com/ and there is another one at http://css3generator.com

In the newest versions of most (if not all) browsers `border-radius: 10px;` works just fine, and within due time, the browser specific declarations will be obsolete.

To make border radius work in IE6, 7 and 8, try **[ms-border-radius js library](http://code.google.com/p/ms-border-radius/)**, though I have not tested it (and somebody has responded that it does not work.) My personal opinion is that if anybody is still using these browsers, the internet must look like a strange and scary place to them on the daily, and thus, they will not miss their rounded corners.

*Aside:*  The method you are trying to use was more applicable when CSS3 was not as widely supported. It was created during a strange period of the Internet when the popularity of IE6 drove countless web developers to find highly non-semantic creative solutions to otherwise simple problems. So thank you Internet Explorer for taking a few years off all of our lives and slowing the progression of web design and development.

Comment: I was under the impression IE8 doesn't support this.

Comment: This is true, but the following solves that problem well (in IE6, 7 and 8!) info: http://code.google.com/p/ms-border-radius/wiki/Usage and source: http://code.google.com/p/ms-border-radius/source/checkout

Comment: msbr looks broken, it throws an exception in IE8 as soon as the script is loaded. It seems to work despite that, but I don't like seeing errors in the status bar.

Comment: What's the error? May be an easy fix, the script is simple enough.

Answer (score 2):

There's always [curvycorners](http://www.curvycorners.net/) as well, it uses native css for speed if the browser supports it or falls back to javascript if the browser doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Can be done easily with jQuery rounded corners [rounded_corner](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aRounded_Corners)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#b1").corner();
 });
```

You don't need to worry about cross browser issues with jQuery approach.

Answer (score 1):

A fantastic summary for all major browsers, telling you how to round each corner or all corners:

http://perishablepress.com/press/2008/11/24/perfect-rounded-corners-with-css/

Answer (score 0):

Instead just put this code in the class where you want to have rounded corners .it will definitely work.

```
-khtml-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
```